# How to display sum result of two column field even if one field is empty in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having difficulty to show total value of two fileds in sql. I am getting result of first row but my second row is not showing any result just displaying empty.

Tabel Name: NumberTable

```
ID  VALUE1  VALUE2
===================
1   1       2
2   2
```

Sql Query

```
Select id, (VALUE1  + VALUE2) as Total_Salary  From NumberTable;
```

The following output that I am getting after running this query

```
ID  TOTAL
1    3 
2    -
```

But I want output like this:

```
ID  TOTAL
1    3 
2    2
```

Comment: You can always use `...SUM(NVL(VALUE1,0))… `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
coalesce(value1, 0) + coalesce(value2, 0)
```

The addition operator returns `NULL` if either argument is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Please use NVL function,

```
Select id, (NVL(VALUE1, 0)  + NVL(VALUE2, 0)) as Total_Salary  From NumberTable;
```